# How to update the Group Number in a sequence in all rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in which the data is stored as:

[image]

I want only the Branch column to be updated in a way that the sequence becomes continuous. Means the rows from ID 1 to 4 would have same value, but the rows from ID 5 to 7 will have Branch as 3, rows 8 and 9 would have Branch as 4, rows from 10 to 12 would have  branch as 5 and so on.

My desired output would look like this:

[image]

I don't want the rows to be reordered, means the rows would have same sequence as they are now with continuous increasing ID column, and only the Branch column to be ordered.
I tried it doing with looping but that part is becoming so large and error prone that I was thinking of some other direct approach.
Is it possible through CTEs or any other approach?
How can I do so?

Comment: `the rows from ID 1 to 4 would have same value` ... this doesn't agree with your expected output.  I don't understand your logic for reassigning branch numbers.

Comment: Ok lets forget the rows with ID 1 and 2 have Branch 2, then all the rows from 1 to 4 will have to be new branch and so on. Is it clear now? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: the rows from ID 1 to 4 would have same value, by this I meant rows 1 and 2 would have branch as 1and rows from 3 and 4 would have Branch as 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/SLCGH28035)**

I use more columns than necesary just to show what is going on. rn is just to show how the grp is create. You only need grp to the final result.

The idea is create a group sequence based on Id. Then using `DENSE_RANK()` you get your desire sequence.

This assume `ID` is sequential number without holes, if your ID has holes, you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create a sequence.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Branch] ORDER BY [Id]) as rn,
           [Id] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Branch] ORDER BY [Id]) as grp
    FROM Table1
)    
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY grp) as new_branch
FROM cte
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant answer.  Wish I could have seen what the OP wanted +1.

Comment: Prefect, exactly what I wanted, thanks a ton! Cheers!